# Counting selected checkboxes apiece

Tags: php

I have created a form to select category items from main category. Here I use checkboxes to select category item. In my form there are many main categories and have its own subcategories. Example Courses and its subjects.

With this form I need to check how many sub items have selected for a one category. And also I need to look over at least one sub category has selected in all main category and if it is ok want to limit upto 10 sub categories to select.

I tried it something like this.. but here its count all selected subcategories.

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['sub-category']) && is_array( $_POST['sub-category'])) {    
    $totalCategory = count( $_POST['sub-category']);

    if ( $totalCategory >= 1 && $totalCategory <= 10 ) {

        $_SESSION['sub-category'] = $_POST['sub-category'];                 
        $url = BASE_URI . 'register.php'; // Define the URL:        
                header("Location: $url");
                exit(); // Quit the script.         

    } else {        
        echo 'ERROR: Please select atleast 1, not more than 10.';           
    }           
} else {                
    echo 'ERROR: Please select atleast one category.';  
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This is PHP I use to generate from

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{catId:subID}' name='subject{$lastCatId}[]' />{$lastCatName}";
```

Them HTML generate something like this..

```
<h3>Main Category 01 
    <input type='checkbox' value='3:4' name='subject3[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='3:6' name='subject3[]' />sub category

<h3>Main Category 02 
    <input type='checkbox' value='4:6' name='subject4[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='4:2' name='subject4[]' />sub category

<h3>Main Category 01 
    <input type='checkbox' value='5:8' name='subject5[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='5:4' name='subject5[]' />sub category
```

Problem is how I get sub categories' values separately and then need to count...

I hope someone help me out...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When naming your check boxes, use this format:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[math][algebra]">
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[math][calculus]">
```

in PHP:

```
<?php
    $subjects = $_POST['subject'];
    $math = $subjects['math'];
    $algebra = $math['algebra'];
...
```

That is the basic idea.

Comment: You'll need to figure out which values were posted before just assuming they are there, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h3>Main Category 01 
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_1' name='main_cat_1_subject[]' />sub category1
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_2' name='main_cat_1_subject[]' />sub category2
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_3' name='main_cat_1_subject[]' />sub category3
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_4' name='main_cat_1_subject[]' />sub category4

<h3>Main Category 02 
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_1' name='main_cat_2_subject[]' />sub category1
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_2' name='main_cat_2_subject[]' />sub category2
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_3' name='main_cat_2_subject[]' />sub category3
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_4' name='main_cat_2_subject[]' />sub category4

<h3>Main Category 01 
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_1' name='main_cat_3_subject[]' />sub category1
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_2' name='main_cat_3_subject[]' />sub category2
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_3' name='main_cat_3_subject[]' />sub category3
<input type='checkbox' value='sub_cat_4' name='main_cat_3_subject[]' />sub category4
```

And the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['main_cat_1_subject']) && !empty($_POST['main_cat_1_subject'])){
    $main_cat_subjects = $_POST['main_cat_1_subject'];
    //do the stuff.
    foreach($main_cat_subjects as $index => $main_cat_subject){
        //Sub category items by index here.
    }
} else {
    echo 'Please select atleast on subject for Main Category 1';
    //redirect or die
}
```

Repeat this loop for all the categories and change the names in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: can I know how I check selected sub category items separately with isset(). because my checkboxes name's value generating dynamically..

Comment: You'll get three different arrays for each category. Loop over them to check individual values.

Comment: Its ok.. But problem is how I check sub-categories with ISSET(). How I detect which value has in '$_POST' array.. because it is generating dynamically.

Comment: If you for loop over the arrays for the main category, you will get the dynamically generated values automatically! I have edited my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Change your html code to

```
<h3>Main Category 01 
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat1[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat1[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat1[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat1[]' />sub category

<h3>Main Category 02 
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat2[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat2[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat2[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat2[]' />sub category

<h3>Main Category 01 
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat3[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat3[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat3[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='' name='sub_cat3[]' />sub category
```

And submit the form, which will give you the out put

```
$count_cat1 = count($_POST['sub_cat1']);
$count_cat2 = count($_POST['sub_cat2']);
$count_cat3 = count($_POST['sub_cat3']);
```

You can put it in a loop to reduce the code length.

Comment: my form is creating dynamically through a loop.. Then how I named checkboxes like this in my form.

Comment: Change the name something like this in your loop name="sub_cat<?php echo $cat_id; ?>[]"

Comment: can you tell me how $_['sub-category-name]. Now it generating dynamically. Isn't it?